# number of diagonal components in term of determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In linear algebra a determinant of an nxn matrix is the sum n! terms each of which is the product of n components of the matrix. One of the terms contain all n diagonal components. It appears that none contain exactly n-1 diagonal components. (I tested it for 2x2,3x3, 4x4 matrices.) There are many with fewer diagonal components. Is it true that none contain exactly n-1 diagonal components?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. If your matrix is $(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$, then each term of the determinant is $\pm\prod_{i=1}^na_{i\sigma(i)}$, shere $\sigma$ is some permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. But then either $\sigma$ is the identity permutation, in which case you get the product of all elements of the main diagonal, or there are at least two distinct elements $j,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with $\sigma(j)\ne j$ and $\sigma(k)\ne k$. Then $\prod_{i=1}^na_{i\sigma(i)}$ has at most $n-2$ entries from the main diagonal.

Comment: Did you mean $\pm\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i\sigma\left(i\right)}$? In which case the determinant itself is
$$\det{\left(A\right)}=\sum_{\sigma}{\sigma_\pm\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i\sigma\left(i\right)}}$$where the sum is over all permutations of $\sigma$ and $\sigma_\pm=\pm1$ depending on whether it is an odd or even permutation. That explains the $n!$ terms. Now I suddenly remember the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Determinants) and its use with determinants. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I wrote $\sum$ instead of $\prod$. Sorry about that.